# CAD Equivalent of Maplex and VBScript for Labeling

Tags: labeling, autocad, vbscript, civil3d

Is there a CAD equivalent of maplex functionality and VBScript usage to produce custom labels?

I'm pulling a shapefile into CAD, but not sure what support there is to intelligently label the information behind the features.

Comment: What kind of CAD software are you using? In AutoCAD Map 3D there are two ways you can do labeling that I can think of. Although not with nearly as many options as you get with Maplex though.

Comment: We are using 2015 Civil 3D.

Comment: Have never used Civil 3D.  And what is available in Map 3D is rather limited compared to what you are looking for.